# react setstate accepted object is different between in setInterval and in onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'am puzzled by the `setState()` accepted object.The code link is here https://codepen.io/DRL9/pen/jadbWq and the code is as follow:

```
class Counter extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        intervalCount: 1,
        buttonCount: 1
    };
    this.increment = 1;
    this.intervalId = null;
}
tick() {
    this.setState({
        intervalCount: this.state.intervalCount + this.increment
    });
    this.setState({
        intervalCount: this.state.intervalCount + this.increment
    });
}
onClick() {
    this.setState({
        buttonCount: this.state.buttonCount + this.increment
    });
    this.setState({
        buttonCount: this.state.buttonCount + this.increment
    });
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
}
componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
}
render() {
    return <div>
        <div>
            interval counter: {this.state.intervalCount}
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>increment</button>
        <div>
            button counter: {this.state.buttonCount}
        </div>
    </div>;
}
}
```

I expect that `intervalCount` will increment **1** like the behavior when I click increment button. However, it increment **2** each tick. 
The only different is that one updated is in `setInterval` function and the other updated is in `onClick` function.

Why are their behavior different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't talk in absolutes regarding the timing of `setState` as it is, by definition, **unpredictable**. The state changes may be delayed to some time in the future, and this behavior may be different depending on the version of React that you are using.

In the example provided, React is delaying state updates until the `onClick` handler has finished running. React knows when this handler is finished running because we are passing the handler through JSX's `onClick` (which is then processed internally by React):

```
// React processes the onClick handler below
<button id="btn" onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>increment</button>
```

If we were to instrument the `onClick` logic ourselves, by manually grabbing the `button` element from the DOM and adding a click event listener that calls our `onClick` handler, the `button` updates identically to the `setInterval` (React doesn't know that we are updating state within a click handler, so it chooses not to make the optimization of batching the calls to `setState`).

See this **[codepen](https://codepen.io/chrissantos1995/pen/YEBwKz)**, where the button counter has a click handler manually added to it in the `componentDidMount` function as opposed to using JSX's `onClick`. Notice that the button counter now increments in intervals 2 instead of 1.

I want to stress that this behavior is **not deterministic** and you should never use `this.state` within your `setState` function. Instead, you want to use the variation of `setState` that accepts an **updater** function that contains the previous state. Then, build your new state from the state passed to the updater:

```
this.setState(state => ({
    buttonCount: state.buttonCount + this.increment
}));
```

See this **[codepen](https://codepen.io/chrissantos1995/pen/QOYywq)**, which uses an updater to update the button counter, producing the expected effect of updating the button counter in intervals of 2.

For more info on `setState` see the **[official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)**.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation for setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. For better perceived performance, React may delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.

This is saying that when you reference state data (`this.state.buttonCount` or `this.state.intervalCount`) immediately after you've changed it using `setState` (as you do in both functions on the second `setState` command) *the behavior will be unpredictable*.  Maybe `setState` immediately updates the state data, as it seems to be doing with `intervalCount`, and maybe `setState` waits to update the state data so it can batch it later, as it seems to be doing with `buttonCount`.  As a developer we should avoid exposing ourselves to such unpredictable behavior by using other variables when we want to modify the state multiple times during the same event.

As to why `intervalCount` is fairly consistently being updated immediately (and thus incrementing the second time) and `buttonCount` is consistently being batched (and only incrementing one time for the two calls to `setState`) my guess is this: `onClick` is triggered by a user interaction so the React engine probably guesses that during user interactions a lot of state may be changing, so it batches the calls to setState, maybe until the event fully propagates.  `tick`, on the other hand, is triggered by an internal callback without any user interaction being processed, so the React engine probably guesses it's safe to update state right away without batching.

Comment: Thanks. I can understand your guess. Can you provide references that prove your guess?

Comment: I don't think the React team care to specify the rules so developers don't come to depend on it.  It's probably more complicated than that anyways - might be different if there are multiple components, a lot of recent user interaction, etc.  The answer to your question of 'why is it different behavior' is 'the behavior is supposed to be unpredictable'.